# How to capture result of replace-regexp-in-string in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to learn Emacs Lisp. I would like to remove some white space from a string. I started with the following test case:

```
(defun test-fun (str)
  (interactive)
  (let ((ss str)) 
       (replace-regexp-in-string "[ ]+" "" ss)
    (message ss)))
(test-fun "He   llo")
```

However, evaluating this in my Scratch buffer shows that no space is removed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a correction:

```
(defun test-fun (str)
  (let ((ss (replace-regexp-in-string "[ ]+" "" str)))
    (message ss)))
```

`interactive` is only useful for interactive command, so you don't need it here.
Also take note of order of evaluation.

Comment: Perfect! This works.. So the point is that `replace-regexp-in-string` does not change its parameter, `ss`, in my case, but rather returns the modified string?

Comment: Correct. From `C-h f replace-regexp-in-string`: "Return a new string containing the replacements."